# Which is invoked first Virtual Service or Destinationrule?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, istio

I have a confusion between Virtual Service and Destinationrule on which one is executed first?
Let’s say I have below configs,

Destinationrule -

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: movies
  namespace: aio
spec:
  host: movies
  subsets:
  - labels:
      version: v1
    name: version-v1
  - labels:
      version: v2
    name: version-v2
---
```

VirtualService

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: movies
  namespace: aio
spec:
  hosts:
  - movies
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: movies
        subset: version-v1
      weight: 10
    - destination:
        host: movies
        subset: version-v2
      weight: 90
---
```

I read somewhere that,
A VirtualService defines a set of traffic **routing rules** to apply when a host is addressed.
DestinationRule defines policies that apply to traffic intended for service **after routing has occurred.**
Does this mean Destinationrules are invoked after Virtualservices?

I have a small diagram, is my understanding correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

According to [istio](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/) documentation about `DestinationRule`:

> DestinationRule defines policies that apply to traffic intended for a service after routing has occurred.

And for [`VirtualService`](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/):

> A VirtualService defines a set of traffic routing rules to apply when a host is addressed.

There is an youtube video: [Life of a Packet through Istio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZrZlx2fmcM) it explains in detail the order of processes that are applied to a packet going through the istio mesh.